# How to pass values to another page from repeater control to show full details of one specific record

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, repeater

This is my code for the aspx side. I have all the records showing but I want to click into it and view one record at a time. I get no errors but nothing shows on the page when I click the link.

```
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

                <asp:Repeater ID="rptrComments"  runat="server" 
             OnItemCommand="rptList_ItemCommand">

               <ItemTemplate>
                    <div id="Container">


            <div id="OverveiwWrapper">
   <table id="TblOverveiw" style="/*border: 1px solid black;*/ width:165PX;  
             height:170PX" >
             <tr>
             <td id="TdTitle"> <%#Eval("IdeaTitle")%></b></td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td id="TdStatus"><%#Eval("IdeaDescription")%></td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td id="TdPrice"><%#Eval("Category")%></td></tr>
            <tr>
    <td id="TdAddress"><%#Eval("Date")%></td></tr>

          </table>
 </div>
          <div id="DescriptionWrapper">
        <p id="PropType">  Property type : <%#Eval("IdeaTitle")%>  </p>
         <p id="PropDescription"  ><%#Eval("Category")%></p>
       <asp:LinkButton  ID="testing"  runat="server" Text="More Details" 
      CommandName="click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("IdeaTitle")%>' 
        Visible="true" ></asp:LinkButton>
     <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server"></asp:DataList>
         </div>
           </div>

        </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:Repeater>
```

This is the code for the logic behind I am trying to grab the value from the link and send it to the other page.  I get no errors but logically its not working because when I click to go on the page nothing is displayed

```
        protected void rptList_ItemCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "click")
            {
                Session["Data"] = e.CommandArgument.ToString(); 
                Response.Redirect("ViewIdea3.aspx");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Please share the code of ViewIdea3.aspx.cs file and also it will be better if you can pass the IdeaTitle via querystring parameter instead of saving it in a session.

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ViewIdea3.aspx.cs" Inherits="SimpleLogin.ViewIdea3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
           
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
 I dont have any thing in this page i though sending data to it would just appear

Comment: How can i pass the idea via qery string

Comment: Saving data is session will not automatically populate it on the ViewIdea3.aspx page. Better approach is to just pass the IdeaId via querystring parameter and then fetch more detailed data for the idea based on the id passed as a querystring param and then display that detailed data

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do is this
Instead of using a linkbutton with command argument use a hyperlink with href and querystring parameter:

```
<a href='ViewIdea3.aspx?IdeaId=<%#Eval("ID")'>More Details</a>
```

Then in ViewIdea3.aspx Page_Load event do something like this:

```
if(!IsPostBack && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Querystring["IdeaId"])) {

  //Query database based on IdeaId and once data is fetched populate grid with details
}
```

Comment: what would i put in between the if post back

Comment: Code for fetching the specific idea details based on the id passed as querystring parameter

Comment: if(!IsPostBack && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Querystring["IdeaId"])) {
 Session["Data"] = e.CommandArgument.ToString(); 
                Response.Redirect("ViewIdea3.aspx");
  
}

Comment: would it be this

Comment: and also it looks that is supposed to go to page load